# Laravel Excel File download from Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I wanna generate the excel from laravel with PHPspreadsheet (PHP Lib) and then return the xlsx file to the frontend to trigger the download function. is that possible?

JSX Part

```
axios
.get(
    "/excel/export/dashboardTable", {}
)
.then(resp => {
    //success callback
    if (resp.status == 200) {
        const blob = new Blob([resp.data], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
        let link = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "Customers.xlsx";
        a.href = link;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    _.forEach(error.response.data.errors, function (
        value,
        el
    ) {
        toastr.error("Error", value, {
            onHidden: function onHidden() { }
        });
    });
})
.finally(() => { });
```

Backend Part

```
$response = response()->streamDownload(function () use ($spreadsheet) {
    $writer = new xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('php://output');
}, "Dashboard.xlsx");

$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');

return $response;
```

Comment: I thought you were talking about laravel-excel package. It is created exactly for your task.  Look at how easy it is to export your excel file https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/

Comment: @AnuratChapanond how about streamDownload function? There's no way to do it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, streamdownload means you create a spreadsheet without writing to a disk before sending, then yes laravel-excel can do that without having to call streamdownload().

Comment: Got it, but is that possible to download the via js not using PHP or link?

Comment: you can just have your js call the url for the excel file. e.g. location.href = /url/ or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solve: change the responseType to Blob.

```
axios
.get(
    "/excel/export/dashboardTable", {
    responseType: 'blob' //Change the responseType to blob
}
)
.then(resp => {
    //success callback
    if (resp.status == 200) {
        toastr.success("Success", "Updated successfully!", {
            onHidden: function onHidden() {
                let blob = new Blob([resp.data], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
                let link = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                let a = document.createElement("a");
                a.download = "file.xlsx";
                a.href = link;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }
        });
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    _.forEach(error.response.data.errors, function (
        value,
        el
    ) {
        toastr.error("Error", value, {
            onHidden: function onHidden() { }
        });
    });
})
.finally(() => { });
```